# Why would the clear command won't work with nohup sleep?

Tags: nohup

Here are 2 code examples. Both are `nohup` codes in a bash string. The first one does the job and second doesn't. I ask why.

```
sudo apt-get purge zip unzip
nohup bash -c " sleep 20s; apt-get install zip unzip; " &
```

The above command is executed in the background and installas these software (I've affirmed it by executing the stdin "`zip`".

---

```
nohup bash -c " sleep 20s; clear; "
```

This command runs in the foreground but doesn't clear the tty. Why is that? What could I do to make it clear the screen of the current session? Is there any argument/way of execution/script that I could run together with the command, that might help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does clear command work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124762/how-does-clear-command-work)

Comment: No - that doesn't answer this question.  OP doesn't understand that stdout is redirected.

Comment: @ThomasDickey It explains that certain codes (ANSI escape codes) are written to the stdout which gets redirected here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clear` program is writing to the *standard output*, which is *redirected* by the `nohup` command.  So that has no effect on the terminal.

You can see the output (from `clear`) in `nohup.out`.

You could do this instead:

```
nohup bash -c " sleep 20s; clear >/dev/tty; "
```

which tells the shell to redirect the output of `clear` to the `tty` device.  You could use the `tty` command to identify the terminal *device* which you are using, e.g.,

```
    nohup bash -c " sleep 20s; clear > $(tty); "
```

but in most cases both will work.

You may get a warning from `nohup`, which can be quieted:

```
    nohup bash -c " sleep 20s; clear > $(tty); " 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: @Benia `nohup` does not want to redirect to tty, it explicitly checks the type of the stdout (and stderr), the idea to prevent it from writing to something which might not exist anymore.

Comment: @Benia, if you don't want `nohup` to redirect to a file, don't use `nohup`.

Comment: @Thomas, the command works but brings `ignoring input and appending output to ‘/root/nohup.out’` and then the effect is seen. BUT, if I do `ctrl+c`, it brakes execution (this won't happen if I don't use `>/dev/tty`). How could I do `ctrl+c` without destroying the command?

Comment: ctrl+c affects the command because you did not add "&" on the end, but this is getting away from the original question (there are more pitfalls with nohup to explore in other questions).